# Casting a generic object to an object with an interface of the generic type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, type-conversion, derived

I have the following code:

```
public class EntityFilter<T>
{}

public interface IEntity
{}

public class TestEntity : IEntity
{}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        var ef = new EntityFilter<TestEntity>();

        DoSomething((EntityFilter<IEntity>)ef); // <- casting fails
    }

    public static void DoSomething(EntityFilter<IEntity> someEntityFilter)
    {
    }
}
```

Visual Studio says:

```
Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApplication1.EntityFilter<ConsoleApplication1.TestEntity>' to 'ConsoleApplication1.EntityFilter<ConsoleApplication1.IEntity>'
```

I cannot convert the DoSomething method to be generic and accept `EntityFilter<T>` because in my application the type of T is unknown at the moment of DoSomething call. The type will be determined later inside of DoSomething using reflection.

**How can I pass the ef variable to the DoSomething method without making the DoSomething method generic?**

Comment: Why can you not create `ef` as an `EntityFilter<IEntity>` to start with?

Comment: Why cant u make your method generic? Thats the right thing to do: `method<T>(EntityFilter<T> ef) where T : IEntity`

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Please provide information on the error you get.

Comment: Edited - created a full example and explained why I cannot create generic method. But I could change the type of someEntityFilter to something else if it will help to solve the issue. I just don't know, how.

Comment: @Martin, you lose absolutely nothing if you do `DoSomething<T>(EntityFilter<T> someEntity) where T : IEntity`. You need not specify `T` at all when you're doing the call. `T` is inferred as `TestEntity` rightly

Comment: @nawfal: oh, thanks, you are right. It seems, inference will do the trick this time, so I don't need that ugly casting and at the same time I don't have to explicitly specify T for DoSomething.

Comment: I agree with the others that making your method generic is the way to go.  But what you are talking about can be done using [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `EntityFilter<T>` could be derived from an interface and that interface had a covariant generic parameter, you could do what you are asking without generics in the method.

Notice the "out" keyword in the `IEntityFilter<out T>` definition.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ef = new EntityFilter<TestEntity>();

        DoSomething(ef);
    }

    public static void DoSomething(IEntityFilter<IEntity> someEntityFilter)
    {
    }
}

public interface IEntityFilter<out T>
{ }

public class EntityFilter<T> : IEntityFilter<T>
{ }

public interface IEntity
{ }

public class TestEntity : IEntity
{ }
```

Comment: FYI, Covariance and Contravariance for generic types was introduced in .Net 4.0, so you would need .Net 4.0 or higher for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a good solution for me, especially because my class contains many other non-generic methods. So that single DoSomething generic method just "doesn't fit". Also I just found that the following cast works fine even if I don't specify "out" for T: var ef = (IEntityFilter<EntityBase>)new EntityFilter<TestEntity>();

Comment: ... but then I get runtime exception when casting, so "out" is really needed anyway.